# How to get full output from Python script inside VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net

I've successfully coded it to run the Python script and return the output. But unfortunately, it only returns the last line. I was wondering if there was a way to get the full output from the script?

If anyone is interested, here is the code to run the script in the background and return the final line of output.

```
Dim proc As Process = New Process
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" 'Default Python Installation
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "RunImageChecker.py arg1 arg2" 'Python script and arguments
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'required for redirect.
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 'captures output from commandprompt.
proc.Start()
AddHandler proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proccess_OutputDataReceived
proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
proc.WaitForExit()
MsgBox(Value)
TextBox1.Text = Value
```

**Note:** The python script has to be in the same folder as your program or it won't work. I wish there was a way around this, but I'm unable to find one.

Comment: You can use a full path if you don't want the current folder `C:\path\to\RunImageChecker.py`

Comment: Have you looked into how many lines of output that `proc.BeginOutputReadLine()` captures?

Comment: Why not `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into your suggestions.